# How to set the nested tree view list to be compressed instead of expanded by default?

Tags: javascript, treeview, nested-lists

The nested tree view list is by default expanded on my page when I load it. How do I set the default to a compressed nested view list?

```
$(function () {
  $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
  $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
      var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
      if (children.is(":visible")) {
          children.hide('fast');
          $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('fa-plus-square').removeClass('fa-minus-square');
      } else {
          children.show('fast');
          $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('fa-minus-square').removeClass('fa-plus-square');
      }
      e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

The problems is with my javascript, it automatically collapses/expands the list by default. How do I get collapse only on click?

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('.parent_li').find(' > ul > li').hide();` to hide all of the children elements initially:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');
    $('.parent_li').find(' > ul > li').hide(); // This new line hides all children after the page fully loads
```

Let me know if that's not what you meant.

Here's your updated fiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/csuojrhy/9/

Comment: Hey @zeterain, that's very close to what I wanted. In your updated fiddle, when the list is collapsed on click, the 'collapse' icons show a - instead of a +...... do you understand what I mean ?